# how to make an image that is rectangle turn into a circle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

I have a RecyclerView that has an image in it and I want the image to reduce down to about half of it's size whilst it becomes a circle then I want the animation to stand for a set amount of time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if extra detail is required please comment and i will do my best. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Picasso to set the image

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(imgSource)
  .transform(new CircleTransform())
  .resize(128, 128)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView);
```

For transformation class

```
    public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size/2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

For dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: In a sentence you are a genius. but i was wondering whether you know how to slow the transition. also it goes blurry not a major issue but if you know how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. finally, just out of interest what does resize(128, 128); mean?

Comment: With the .load function i was wondering what would you put in there with a recycler View which has various images?